# Sort string contents as Datetime c#

Tags: file, sorting, c#-4.0, datetime, stream

I have a file that has string lines that contains data, and date & time value as string.
each line is a fixed width line.

I would like to sort that file rows by the date and time that is in each line.
Then, write the sorted Lines back to the file.
I tried thinking and searching on how to acomplish that, but this time I am clueless.
Hopefully  some of you can help me with this issue.

here is an example of how my rows looks like :

1. date | startTime | endTime | data.....

20/07/2014 08:00 09:00 0001                                               0 F T
21/07/2014 08:00 10:00 0001                                               0 F T
27/07/2014 07:00 08:30 0001                                               0 F T
01/04/2015 13:00 14:00 0001                                               0 F T
01/05/2015 13:00 14:00 0003                                               0 F T
03/08/2014 20:00 22:00 0005                                               0 F T
04/08/2014 23:00 23:59 0200                                               0 F T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reading rows from a file, collect all the rows in a List of string type and sort that list like this:

```
List<string> myList;
//add the rows in the list
```

and then sort the myList like this:

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(p => p.Substring(0)).ToList();
```

or

```
myList.Sort();
```

And then write sorted myList back to the file.

You can also use the array to hold the collection.

But this will sort the rows as alphabetically not by date.

**To sort by EndTime if Date and StartTime are same then you can try this:**

```
    string[] dataRows = {"20/07/2014 08:00 09:00 0001 0 F T", 
    "21/07/2014 08:00 10:00 0001 0 F T",
    "27/07/2014 07:00 08:30 0001 0 F T",
    "01/04/2015 13:00 14:00 0001 0 F T",
    "01/05/2015 13:00 14:00 0003 0 F T",
    "03/08/2014 20:00 22:00 0005 0 F T",
    "04/08/2014 23:00 23:59 0200 0 F T"};

    List<RowModel> myList = new List<RowModel>();

    foreach (string line in dataRows)
    {
        var row = line.Split(' ');
        string startDateTime = row[0] + " " + row[1];
        string endDateTime = row[0] + " " + row[2];
        myList.Add(new RowModel { StarDatetTime =  Convert.ToDateTime(startDateTime), EndDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(endDateTime), Data = line });
    }

    var myData = myList.OrderBy(x => x.StarDatetTime).ThenBy(x =>x.EndDateTime).Select(x=>x.Data).ToList();
```

The RowModel class I have created as:

```
public class RowModel
{
    public DateTime StarDatetTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Now your sorted text lines will be in myData.

**For the date locale:**

***DateTime.ParseExact()*** or ***DateTime.TryParseExact()*** can be used to get the exact format(dd/MM/yyyy, MM/dd/yyyy, etc.) which required.

Comment: This is a good idea but the date format in the example is not sortable.  He would get the file not sorted by date, but by text.  This is not the same.

Comment: Here we can do one thing more, split all the rows by space and add each element(date(convert to date), starttime(convert to time), endtime, etc) in the list then list can be sorted as required

Comment: @AmanVirdi This works Great with one adjusment :
instead of p.Substring(0) I did Convert.ToDateTime(p.Substring(0,16))
And it works great.

Comment: One question : is there a way to set a secondary sort in case 2 rows have the same value for date and start time ?
I have also end time and I would like to sort the lines in which that those with the same value of Substring(0,16) , will be also sorted by the end time that is in the row.

Comment: Ok that's great. Yes you can do that by by creating a class of properties

Comment: And use .ThenBy() function

Comment: Careful about using `Convert.ToDateTime` here.  That will use the current locale's format, which may or may not align to the `dd/MM/yyyy` format found in the data file.  In general, when you know the format, you should use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead.

Comment: Matt Johanson, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to create a small class, let's call it DataLine, that represents your file. At a minimum this class will contain a DateTime for the Date and a string to store the line itself.  Then I would create a method that parses the existing file, and created one DataLine object per line, and add all these new objects in a List. The generic list object can be easily sorted.  And finally you loop the list using a foreach and you write everything to a new file.

Here is my example, **tested with the dataset you provided**.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        // open the file and gets the lines
        string[] content = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\test.txt");

        var data = new List<DataLine>();
        foreach (string textLine in content)
        {
            var lineObj = new DataLine();
            string dateText = textLine.Split(' ').First();
            lineObj.LineDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateText, "dd/MM/yyyy", provider);
            lineObj.Line = textLine;
            data.Add(lineObj);
        }

        // sort the lines by date
        IOrderedEnumerable<DataLine> sortedData = data.OrderBy(x => x.LineDate);

        File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\text.new.txt", sortedData.Select(x => x.Line).ToList());
    }

    public class DataLine
    {
        public DateTime LineDate { get; set; }
        public string Line { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would split each line(entire file) into a 2d array, then do a compare on the dates, swapping elements when needed

[20/07/2014, 08:00, 09:00, 0001, 0, F,T]
[21/07/2014, 08:00, 10:00, 0001, 0, F, T]

// descending order

if[i][j] < [i+1][j]
{

swap([i],[i+1])
}

this is just an idea to get you started